# How to pass a base64 encoded file to an http post request in ruby irb?

Tags: ruby, http

I am trying to use a http post request, but the request has a base64 encoded file in it. And I am getting an error 414, uri too long. I there a woraround for this?
d[0] contains the base64 encoded file.

```
Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse("https://recruit.zoho.in/recruit/private/xml/Candidates/uploadDocument?authtoken=AUTH_Token&scope=recruitapi&version=2&country=RU&fileName=#{a[0]}&documentData=#{d[0]};"), { a: 1 })

<head><title>414 Request-URI Too Large</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>414 Request-URI Too Large</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you share your post form as well

Comment: You would put the file in the URL for a GET request, not a POST. Send the base64 as a POST param not as part of the query string.

Comment: anothermh is right, you can't redefine how long a URI is allowed to be. If the payload is longer than the RFC allows (a[0] + d[0] in this case), you'll need to provide it within the body of the request. Besides, if you are using a HTTP post, one would expect the contents to be in the body of the request, not the URI itself.

Comment: Yeah, the comment was helpful. The problem was solved.